# Как кэшировать данные, если есть более 1000записей?

Tags: php, кэширование, memcached

Всем привет!
Назрел такой вопрос, по поводу кэширования данных.

Есть база, в ней 1000 (может будет и 10000, взяли для примера) записей. (Записи - это список товаров, за каждый товар пользователи могут голосовать, и у товара изменяется кол-во голосов).

На сайте выводится по 50записей на 1й странице. Получается 20страниц, больше записей - больше страниц.

Записи сортируются по голосам пользователей, больше голосов - выше запись, и вот вопрос такой, как правильно кэшировать эти записи...

Есть вариант кэшировать в memchache, но вот главный вопрос - как кэшировать.

- Кроном брать все записи из базы, и кэшировать массивом в одну ячейку, а потом через array_slice выбирать определенное кол-во записей
- Каждую просматриваемую страницу пользователем (1,2,3) - отдельно кэшировать, и давать каждой странице название в кэше: "page_1", но так получится проблема, если страница №5 устареет - то на ней возьмуться новые данные, с учетом новых голосов - а на других страницах - будет брать из кэша старые данные.

Или может еще как-то можно?

Кэшировать данные допустимо минут на 30

**Спасибо!**

Comment: А чего данные не брать из базы и кешировать каждую страницу (/часть страницы с голосами)? И сколько вас пользователей посещает, что вам приходится эту статистику кешировать?

Comment: @Visman если брать часть из базы и кешировать отдельно каждую страницу - то на тех станицах, которые не посещают - может остаться инфа которая не устарела по времени кэша, но по голосам - уже не эти товары могу быть смещены, из-за того, что голосовали за другие товары на других страницах.

Comment: @Visman сайта пока-что такового - нет, просто сейчас разрабатываю его - и задумываюсь о таком варианте, что будет нагрузка, если просто выводить из базы с LIMIT, OFFSET

Comment: Храните суммированные данные по голосованию в той же таблицы, где у вас товары хранятся, тогда данные на страницу по товарам и голосам можно выводить из одной таблицы через LIMIT и OFFSET без доп.вычислений. `то на тех станицах, которые не посещают - может остаться инфа которая не устарела по времени кэша, но по голосам - уже не эти товары могу быть смещены,` если на каждый чих будете пересчитывать все страницы в кеше, то у вас сервер рухнет ;) Если к странице не обращались, то ее и пересчитывать не надо до момента обращаения. Если время жизни кеша не истекло, то опять же не пересчитывать.

Comment: @Visman если на странице №1 кто-то проголосует - то на всех остальных страницай прозойдет смешение позиций товаров, и уже те товары будут неактуальны - по позициям. Кэшировать данные допустимо минут на 30

Comment: 10000 записей это смешно, очень вряд ли это вообще понадобится кэшировать, на пару секунд ради пиковых нагрузок разве что